# Can you "carry a child" in your womb?

Tags: word-meaning, word-request, register

Can I use "carry a child" to replace "carry a pregnancy"? Are there any single-word verbs I can use in this sense?

> Surrogacy is an arrangement or agreement whereby a woman agrees to **carry a pregnancy** for another person or persons, who will become the newborn child's parent(s) after birth.

Comment: Could you provide a sample sentence in which we might try to fit a single-word verb? "Carry a child" is in use, according to Google.

Comment: I am curious why you ask for "single-word verbs". And are you specifically asking about surrogacy, or just being pregnant in general terms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would not normally use the term "carry a pregnancy" in everyday English. It is very common to hear the phrase "**to carry a child**" or "**to carry child**". The example you cited appears to be a technical definition that uses the more formal medical language "to carry a pregnancy", but again you would generally not use this phrase in everyday writing or speech.

Other common ways of referring to a pregnancy:

- to be *expecting* (She is expecting.)
- to be *pregnant* (She is pregnant.)
- to be *with child* (She is with child.)

Comment: +1 for the medical language info ( *to carry a pregnancy*). Wouldn't you say that *to carry child* was also a medical collocation, not used colloquially?

Comment: Good point. But I think something like "to carry child to full term", while not colloquial, is fairly common in informal speech/writing and probably shouldn't be grouped as a medical phrase.

Comment: Googles ngrams agrees with you.  Carry a pregnancy being a relatively recent term.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carry+a+child%2Ccarry+a+pregnancy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccarry%20a%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccarry%20a%20pregnancy%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Carry a child" seems a bit old-fashioned in British English (in the past it was possibly a euphemism for "pregnant", which is now the common word in formal speech or writing), but "to miscarry" and "miscarriage" are still commonly used.

Comment: I don't think I've heard "carry a pregnancy" except in reference to when it ended, specifically with "carrying a pregnancy to term."

Comment: At least in the US, "with child" is archaic. I can't comment on other countries.

Comment: @Matt . . .and in the UK. Anyone using 'she is with child' would sound like they were using it ironically, or humorously.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, yes. It is common to say "carry a child" as a euphemism for being pregnant.

Answer (score 0):

For a single word verb with the same meaning, you can use [***gestate***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/gestate). From Collins Dictionaries:

> 1. (transitive) to carry (developing young) in the uterus during pregnancy
>      *‘How incredible would it be to gestate a baby and spawn it?*.
>      *Times, Sunday Times* (2013)’

I should point out that this is a technical-sounding term. In casual conversation it will usually sound tongue-in-cheek, like the example above. This joking sort of usage is how I've mostly used it ("I can't do the dishes, honey, I'm too exhausted from **gestating** all day"). It would fit in your academic-sounding example, though:

> Surrogacy is an arrangement or agreement whereby a woman agrees to **gestate (a[n] embryo/fetus/baby/child)** for another person or persons, who will become the newborn child's parent(s) after birth.